# Finding an element in a DbSet with a composite primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model and am trying to find a specific object in a `DbSet`:

```
public class UserSkill
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("Skill")]
    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried the following two ways of finding a certain `UserSkill` object (I'm passing the `DbSet` of `UserSkills` via the `ViewBag`):

```
ViewBag.UserSkills.Find(new { WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, item.SkillId })
ViewBag.UserSkills.Find(new UserSkill(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, item.SkillId))
```

But in both cases, I get an error:

> The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary key values defined on the entity.

What am I missing? It seems to me that the primary key consists of two columns, and I'm providing the find function with the two values that comprise the primary key.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The signature of `Find` method is `TEntity Find(params Object[] keyValues)` and you can enlist the keys of composite primary key in proper order.

```
ViewBag.UserSkills.Find(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, item.SkillId )
```

Answer (score 8):

To find an entity by composite key you should use this overload

```
ViewBag.UserSkills.Find(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, item.SkillId);
```

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.find%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Column Order numbers are zero-based. Change to 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2. i.e.:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int UserId { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
[ForeignKey("Skill")]
public int SkillId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I've updated the Column Order but that doesn't seem to be affecting the order of parameters in .Find().